# JSF2 Auto update commandButton's redirect page with inputText's value

Tags: redirect, button, jsf-2, input

I have an inputText and a commandButton in a JSF page. The user inputs something and then gets redirected in a result page which also has has an inputText and commandButton with the same functionality. The commandButton should perform some action when clicked and redirect to a REST url (result page) which is constructed by appending the inputText value into a base URL. I tried many things but I did not manage to make this work in the second page. What I tried until now is:

1. Inside the action of the commandButton I call my methods and then return the URL for the redirection since I have the inputText value in my bean. I used AJAX to render the commandButton on a keyup event. This works for page 1 but not for page 2. The problem is that each time a user types a letter, the button is rendered and my methods are called which I do not want as I only want to call them when the user clicks the button.
2. I created a method in my bean in which I put all my methods. I tried both making the method PostConstruct and having an f:event with preRenderView for calling the method. Again with AJAX this does not work since the method is called each time a user types something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The problem is that each time a user types a letter, the button is rendered and my methods are called which I do not want as I only want to call them when the user clicks the button.*

Just don't render the button then. Perhaps you've used a too general client identifier in `<f:ajax render>` attribute like as `@form`. Just replace it something more specific which excludes the button.

---

> *Again with AJAX this does not work since the method is called each time a user types something.*

Just check if it isn't an ajax request.

```
if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().isAjaxRequest()) { 
    // Not an ajax request.
}
```

Comment: But I think I have to render the button because otherwise the action redirect URL won't have the URL with the inputText appended as this will be evaluated once before the rendering of the page. I had it to render just the button until now. Your second suggestion does seem to work. I'm combining it with a preRenderView and it seems that the method is called when the page is refreshed but not when ajax re-renders the button to put the new value. It is weird though because that would mean that ajax calls re-render the view.

Comment: Why should ajax calls not send any HTTP request to JSF? Why should ajax calls not re-render the view? How else should ajax calls get a response?

Comment: What I meant is that I'd guess that only the specified elements are re-rendered by ajax and that this won't affect the listener in the preRenderView since I'd guess that it is only activated when the whole page is reloaded.